# Python simple error regarding checking lengths Need all of the characters

Tags: python

```
import re
global points
import random
print("""
Point System:
~1 Uppercase Letter = 5 Points
~1 Lowercase Letter = 5 Points
~1 From 0-9 = 5 Points
~1 Allocated Symbol = 5 Points
~If Has All Add 10 Points
""")
points = 0

while points < 35:
    p = input("Input Password: ")


    if 8 < len(p) < 24 :
        print(len(p),"Points Added - Length")
        points += (len(p))

    else:
        print("Wrong length, it must be 8 to 24 characters")
        continue

    if re.search("[a-z]", p):
        print("5 Points Added - Lowercase Letter")
        points += 5

    if re.search("[0-9]", p):
        print("5 Points Added - Number")
        points += 5

    if re.search("[A-Z]", p):
        print("5 Points Added - Uppercase Letter")
        points += 5

    if re.search("[!$%^&()_]", p):
        print("5 Points Added - Symbols")
        points += 5

    if points == 20:
        points += 10

    print("You have {} points".format(points))
```

so im new to python and i wanted to create a password checker / point system to go with it. However When i input the password even if i just do a capital letter it still carry's on. but i want to make it so that the password needs to contain all of the above.

Comment: When I run the snippet that you have posted, it doesn't let me carry on if all I enter is a single capital letter. Perhaps you should include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also, change this line `if 8 < len(p) < 24 :` to `if 8 <= len(p) < 24 :` because otherwise the acceptable length is 9 to 24 characters.

Comment: okay thank you but what would specifically challenge the problem of when you run the program and enter single capital letter with a length between 8 and 24 it accepts it however i would like it to make it so that it has to except all of the characters above to carry on.

Comment: That is exactly what I am saying: I do not see that behaviour. Perhaps you want to post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Antimony to assist you i created a code that works regarding checking if its valid but i need assistance putting them both together.

Comment: p = input("Input your password: ")
    AGrade = True
    while AGrade:  
        if (len(p)<8 or len(p)>24):
            break
        elif not re.search("[a-z]",p):
            break
        elif not re.search("[0-9]",p):
            break
        elif not re.search("[A-Z]",p):
            break
        elif not re.search("[!$%^&()_]",p):
            break
        else:
            print("Valid Password")
            AGrade=False
            break

    if AGrade:
        print("Not a Valid Password")